# Omniauth Facebook Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying to access a user's Facebook profile photo for use in my application. These are the steps i have taken with no success:

1. modified the devise.rb in initializers. I added 'image' to info_fields.

   config.omniauth :facebook, "codehere", "codehere", scope: 'email',        info_fields: 'name, email, first_name, last_name, image'
2. in user.rb i added the line:

   user.image = auth.info.image
3. in the view, i try to access the image by such:

it returns undefined method 'image'.

Do i need to add an image column to my database schema?

Answer (score 0):

yes - you should add an image column to your user model

Comment: would i do something like this: rails generate migration add_image_to_users image:string (would it be a string?)

Comment: is the info field value "image" or "cover"?

Comment: your migration is good - the image will most certainly be a string. and you can call it whatever you want - image, cover, image_url, etc.

Comment: i mean for the devise.rb in initializers.

Comment: so, would it look like this: config.omniauth :facebook, "codehere", "codehere", scope: 'email', info_fields: 'name, email, first_name, last_name, image' - or would image be cover instead? cover is in the Facebook documents for info field values.